# Update json string after ruby parse

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I have a JSON object and I have parsed it with ruby. Now i need to update the JSON object with the changed values.  I need to update JSON_STR with the new value "testing". It might sound silly, but i am not getting to it.

```
require 'json'
obj = JSON.parse(JSON_STR) 
obj.each do |doc|
  doc["ref"] = "testing" 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the document you're trying to modify as a constant might not be the best move, it makes things more complicated, but it can be done. You just need to reassign the value of the string with the JSON serialized version of your modified object:

```
JSON_STR.replace(JSON.dump(obj))
```

This will only work if `JSON_STR` is not frozen, and constants often are, so watch out if you get errors.

As a note `obj` is a pretty terrible name for your variable. Try and explain what it is. Even `entries` or `docs` is better here.